# jquery ajax post - not working first time page loads

Tags: php, jquery

I have some ajax/jquery code in one of my pages and the problem I'm having is that it doesn't work the first time the page is loaded. If I refresh the page it works no prob. It does work in firefox first time. All the variables that I'm using are ok as I've alerted them out. I don't get a success or error message. It justr doesn't appear to do anything?

Any ideas?

```
$('.window .request').click(function (e) {              
  var itm = document.getElementById('txtItm').value; 
  var qty = document.getElementById('txtQty').value;
  var msg = document.getElementById('txtMessage').value;
  var op_id = document.getElementById('txtOp_id').value;  

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "do_request.php?msg="+msg+"&itm="+itm+"&qty="+qty+"&op_id="+op_id,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
      document.getElementById('div_main').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('div_success').style.display='block';
      var row_id = document.getElementById('txtRow').value;
      document.getElementById('row'+row_id).style.backgroundColor='#b4e8aa';
    },

    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('Error submitting request.');
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: This just happened to me.  I had a `<form>` and a `<button>`.  I had a click handler on the button that in turn called $.post(...).  The form had no action element.  I was counting on the button to do the work.  I removed the click handler from the button and added `action="javascript:mySubmitFunction()"` to the `<form>` instead.  I guess somehow the lack of action on the form was causing a refresh so I never saw the result from the $.post().  Hope this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine what the problem might be given the information and it sounds like you've not fully tested the page in a consistent manner. It seems likely there is another element on the page affecting the click event, as opposed to the handler logic itself, but there's no way to tell. Make sure you are binding to the click event after the page is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#uniquedomid").bind('click',function(){
    // click handler logic
  });
});
```

Also, as you're new to JQuery, one thing you're going to want to start looking at are all the various ways in which JQuery can improve your life. It does almost everything. But for starters, you're going to want to start using:

```
$("#uniquedomid")
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("uniquedomid")
```

And

```
$("#uniquedomid").val();
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("uniquedomid").value
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointers Oliver I've changed a few things round and started using them. Still no luck on the ajax bit, it's getting as far as "$.ajax({" then doesn't do anyting first time. Mystery.

Comment: try looking at the web log to see if the request actually happens, and put alerts or console logs in your success and error functions to make sure they aren't firing. Also, I believe you can remove the contentType attribute from your ajax options as the utf-8 portion is superfluous and you're not passing JSON. HTH.